# How to Execute a function after rendering in Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom, rendering

I need to make changes in Service file (Not inside Component.ts or directive file), here is my requirement:
1) Needs to add an event listener once the code inside the service renders (Using a 3rd party tool which is providing HTML content as well via the service file - The HTML code can't be found - unless you inspect it and get an id)
2)Why can't we use life cycle hooks inside service.ts file ?

Comment: Could you show sample code

Comment: Please provide more information for question 1. Are you trying to get the html code from service and inject into the html after initialization ?

Answer (score 0):

Q: Why does service files wont have any life cycle hooks ?

A: Life cycle hooks were meant for components. It is because, whenever a user navigates from Component A to component B, the compA is destroyed (dead) and compB is initialized (came to live). Again when the user navigates from compB to compC, the compB will be destroyed and compC will be initialized.

Every component goes through this cycle of initialized and destroyed states, which replicates the life, since they have life cycle hooks.

Where as, a service file is just a helper class for the functioning of the applicaton. It will be initialized when application is created and will not be destroyed untill the user closes the application, since it wont have any hooks attached.